# Call all in decision

Tags: pre-flop

Interesting situation. 
Hold'em tourney, 4 tables of 10 people to start. WSOP rules. 
I make it to the final table, so 10 people left. 
While the dealer was dealing cards to everyone, one of the cards accidently caught the felt and flipped over. Ace of diamonds. (Sadly it was coming to me).
So I'm skipped and it's dealt normally, then I get the last card.

I'm in the big blind, 3 people call the blind, then button raises all in. Small blind folds.
My chip stack is probably in the lower end of the table (I'm probably sitting 7th or 8th). And the button easily has 4x my stack. He's probably 2ed or 3rd.
I look down to QQ.

EDIT: For some clarity, I have about 5 BB total. Also - Only top 3 get paid.

What should I do in this situation? I'll comment what I ended up doing after an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your situation is quite vague, as we don't have information about blinds, chip stacks, etc. You may have the 7th stack with 100 BB or you may have the 7th stack with 5 BB. In each of the cases, the correct play is different.

But **judging only by what you told us**, I would call. It will be a gamble (already a guy shoved, the button and the limpers may as well do it), you may have lower or higher odds, depending on the information you didn't give to us, but I look at the potential winnings and, perhaps, how high I will go up in rankings and the future prize money you may earn.

LE: QQ is not such a crappy hand. You may turn into AA or KK, but you can also see lower pairs, AK, etc.

LE 2: with 5BB is easy call.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the answer -> I edited my question to show I have 5BB.

Comment: Edited answer as well.

Comment: Ended up calling, he had AA :(.In hindsight maybe the argument could be made to avoid the variance, but I think I would still call anyway.

Comment: With 5BB behind, you cannot think about variance. Only doubling up

Comment: I agree, the important thing here is your stack size. With only 5BB, you have to take the shot at tripling up here.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Villain has AA once out of every 221 hands. You don't have a stack to wait for a better hand than the 3rd best hand in holdem.

Comment: @Jonast92 I agree